# How to know how an lm model predicted with variable interaction with R

Tags: r, prediction, lm, predict, interaction

Here is the R code for the lm model, along with its summary output:

`model <- lm(log(Y)~-1+log(X1)+log(X2)/log(X1)+X3+log(1+X4)+X4,df)`

[Summary output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzgM3.png)

The problem is that to make predictions about the future, my variable X3 will take the values ​​2017,2018 which have no known coefficients in the model. I'm trying to figure out how the model predicts to apply a coefficient myself to this new year. Unfortunately, impossible to find the right equation ...

I just want to know how the predict function of this model calculates fitted values?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You have two options: Make X3 a continuous variable (possibly use, e.g., a polynomial) or make it a random effect and use the population mean for prediction. Or, probably preferable, switch to a time series model.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks for your comment. I just want to know how the predict function of this model calculates fitted values?

Comment: Google "treatment contrasts".

Comment: I have the impression that this will not help me answer my question ... I am just looking for the mathematical expression of this model at first.

Comment: Yes, and for that you need to understand dummy encoding. And R uses treatment contrasts for dummy encoding by default.

Comment: Ok, I will try, thanks Roland.